# Changing value detection numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, indexing

How can I make a numpy function that detects the indexes where there is a change in values? Sop since the first number is unique it will include that and from index 0 to 1 the number changes from 24 to 27. So it will have 0 as the first index and so on.

```
import numpy as np

digit_vals = np.array([24, 27, 27, 27,
                       28, 28, 28, 31])
```

Expected output:

```
[0, 1, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
np.where(np.diff(digit_vals, prepend=np.nan))
```

What happens here is that you first use `np.diff`. Its parameters are the following: 1) an array, your digit_vals, and 2) `prepend = np.nan`. The last simply is which values append to `digit_vals` along axis prior to performing the difference.

`np.where()` return the positions at which the differences occur.

Comment: @tlentali If only there was an explanation of it...

Comment: I used a `np.digitize` function to get the values of the `digit_vals ` which are `[0, 1, 4, 7]` but I cannot use ur function o n it for some reason. It gives me an error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`. Would you have any idead on how I could fix it?

Comment: @bullselcuk Can you edit your question with the prior step?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes 
  ok will do so